# Magento 2 How to get category tree (collection) on footer

Tags: magento2, category, layout, template, category-tree

I need to display magento 2 category tree on footer and on some other places. I think best practice is creating a module and call it on desired block (place). How to do that ? I already created a module but it is not working it returns an error "Object DOMDocument should be created."

```
app/code/Muaw/CategoriesList/registration.php
```

content:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Muaw_CategoriesList',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Muaw/CategoriesList/Block/CategorisCollection.phtml

```
<?php
namespace Muaw\CategoriesList\Block;

class CategorisCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryFlatConfig;
    protected $topMenu;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu
    )
    {

        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Return categories helper
     * getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
     * example getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', 0)
     */
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->topMenu->getHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current store categories
     *
     * @param bool|string $sorted
     * @param bool $asCollection
     * @param bool $toLoad
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
     */
    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child store categories
     *
     */
    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
        if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
            $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        } else {
            $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
        }
        return $subcategories;
    }
}
```

app/code/Muaw/CategoriesList/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Muaw\CategoriesList\Block\CategorisCollection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="deleteorderAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="context" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context</item>
                <item name="helper" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category</item>
                <item name="flatstate" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State</item>
                <item name="menu" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

app/code/Muaw/CategoriesList/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Muaw_CategoriesList" setup_version="2.0.1" schema_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Muaw/CategoriesList/view/frontend/template/storecategories.phtml

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true, false, true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($categories as $category):
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            continue;
        }

        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
        if ($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)):
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory):
                    if (!$childrenCategory->getIsActive()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory) ?>"><?php echo $childrenCategory->getName() ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        endif;
    endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>
```

and I called it on my layout file as below

```
 <container name="categories" after="page_top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="categories">
            <block class="Muaw\CategoriesList\Block\CategorisCollection" name="categoriecollection" template="Muaw_CategoriesList::storecategories.phtml"/>
        </container>
```

I don't know what is the wrong with this , please help me by fixing this module or using another method

Comment: Your block should be .php not .phtml. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is thrown by the `getDom()` method from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger.php`

```
public function getDom()
{
    if (!isset($this->domDocument)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Object DOMDocument should be created.')
        );
    }

    return $this->domDocument;
}
```

That is definitely an XML related problem and I'm pretty sure it's caused by your layout file missing some important tags.

I suggest you replace your layout file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="categories" after="page_top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="categories">
            <block class="Muaw\CategoriesList\Block\CategorisCollection" name="categoriecollection" template="Muaw_CategoriesList::storecategories.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```