# Magento 2: How to display sibling categories as child(sub) category?

Tags: magento2

I have all the categories as parent categories, now i want to display all parent category as sub category. is there any way?

Comment: Please share code for more details.

Comment: @Msquare check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you wanna show whole category tree , You can check this answer may this will help you out [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204269/how-to-get-category-tree-in-magento-2/204305)

Thanks

Comment: I did it by creating new tree in Topmenu Block. but this is also corrrect answer. Thank you  , keep helping.

Comment: your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display in admin, then simply drog and drop all categories under ALL categories.

If its to be done on front-end of site then follow [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/204269/29175) as mentioned by @ Shashank Gupta.